# Verify Rolle's theorem for the function $f(x)=\sin{\frac{1}{x}}$ in $[-\frac{1}{3\pi}, \frac{1}{3\pi}]$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Verify Rolle's theorem for the function $f(x)=\sin{\frac{1}{x}}$ in $[-\frac{1}{3\pi}, \frac{1}{3\pi}]$.

$f(x)$ is discontinuous at 0, then how to verify this theorem?

**Edit**:

**Edit**:

If conditions of Rolle's theorem fail to satisfy, show that there exist $c\in[-\frac{1}{3\pi}, \frac{1}{3\pi}]$ such that $f'(x)=0$

Comment: so then Rolle's theorem says nothing about this function. If it says nothing, it can't be wrong. QED

Comment: @Mirko Obviously Rolle's th cannot be wrong. I think the question is asking although f(x) doesn't satisfy all of it's conditions, there is c such that f'(c)=0. How to solve that?

Comment: there exists $c$ such that what? What is the relevance of $c$ in the expression $f'(x)=0$, it does not appear in this expression? Finally why don't you just compute and solve $f'(x)=\frac{-\cos{\frac1x}}{x^2}=0$ so $\frac1x=(2k+1)\frac{\pi}2$ and $x=\frac2{(2k+1)\pi}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

> Pick a=1/4$\pi$, b=1/3$\pi$.
>
> Obviously, we have [a b] $\subset$ [-1/(3$\pi$) 1/(3$\pi$)].
>
> In addition, f is continuous on [a b], differentiable on (a b) and f(a) = f(b) = 0.
>
> All the conditions for Rolle's theorem have been met.
>
> Hence by Rolle's theorem, there is a c in (a b) such that f'(c) = 0. Obviously, c is also in (-1/(3$\pi$) 1/(3$\pi$)) by our choice of [a b].
>
> In this case, we also know c = 2/(7$\pi$) even though Rolle's theorem does NOT provide that information to us. Can you see c is in (-1/(3$\pi$) 1/(3$\pi$))?